# Is it possible to kill the task through psexec command before it even gets chance to execute?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, psexec, deep-freeze

We have over 100 computers in our gaming network. We have deployed Deep Freeze Enterprise on our machines to control the customers' abuse of PCs. That is well taken care of, but there's another problem. We need to update the system periodically to game clients and Windows. So we created a VBScript send keys that is triggered by a batch file. Both the batch file and the .vbs file are kept at root of C:\ on all machines. Then when the time comes, we use the Deep Freeze Enterprise console to remotely execute the batch file using `psexec` commands to start the update process. Until here all goes well.

Here's the deal. We have another software product to manage the PCs in the network that requires the credentials to log in as user or admin. So, the problem is if we want those updates to run, we need to go to each PC and manually enter the credentials to login to Windows as admin. I have read that it's possible to kill the process of that software so that we don't have to enter any credentials in the first place. The question is: Is it possible to kill the task through `psexec` command before it even gets a chance to execute?

We don't want this to happen on every reboot; only when we remotely execute with Deep Freeze.

Comment: I would schedule a take to run every x seconds to check if the specific exe is running in memory and if so to taskkill /f /im <app.exe> if it is found to be running. This could be a different batch script, using Task Scheduler, and running as SYSTEM.

Comment: You cannot kill a task before it starts, for the obvious reason that there is nothing yet to kill. However, you can easily prevent certain programs from running. Have a look at how they did something similar for the parental control (Family Safety). Here are [an article about various options](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/whitelist-program-windows-10).

Comment: @Emperor What triggers the second software to start?  Do you want the second software to simply never run?